# Showing error with imported in Django mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have such a model in my models.py

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True,db_column='device_type_id')
    device_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Meta:
    #  managed = False
    db_table = 'device_type'
```

For the test I tried to add the table to admin view, it's added, but when I try to see the result I have an error:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'device_type.id' in 'field list'")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://172.17.45.9:8001/admin/_my_alfanet_/devicetype/
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1054, "Unknown column 'device_type.id' in 'field list'")
Exception Location: /etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
Python Executable:  /etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/etc/network/scripts',
 '/etc/network/scripts/ansible/lib',
 '/etc/network/scripts',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python27.zip',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/etc/network/scripts/my_alfanet_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 3 Mar 2017 15:18:57 +0000
```

It looks like django try to add it's own column to sql request and this is create an error. Who could help, wich solution could be about this issue?

Comment: This DB is external, it's imported from another project

Comment: coud you add the admin view, admin.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Django requires each model to have exactly one primary key. It [automatically adds a primary key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) `id` to the model, unless you set `primary_key=True` for one of the other fields.

In your case, it looks as if `device_type_id` is the primary key. If so, you can change the model to:

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    device_type_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    device_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I've removed `db_column='device_type_id'` because it matches the field name. I've also removed `blank=True` and `null=True` because the primary key cannot be null.

If your database automatically creates the `device_type_id`, then you should use [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#autofield) instead of `IntegerField`. If not, you'll have to manually set `device_type_id` when creating new device types in the database.